# Connect Cookies for Homescreen'd HTML5 Apps?

Tags: ios, node.js, cookies, local-storage, connect

So for some reason once you add an HTML5 app to the homescreen on iOS is loses the ability to work with cookies. I'm using a node.js server running connect.

I've seen others solve this problem with things like  http://rubygems.org/gems/rack_iphone_web_app

Is there anything that does this for connect cookies? If not what it would it look like to translate them to localStorage myself?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the same code as in your link, it looks like it takes the current cookie in general and stores that - nothing rack specific!

Comment: Could you just provide a bit more explanation, possible posting the code you're referring to? What is `var RESEND_REQUEST = {{RESEND}};` and `RESEND_REQUEST = RESEND`?

Comment: That part is about whether the app should reload after reading the cookie from localStorage, I'm guessing to make sure the cookie is sent. I would remove that check and just always reload after reading the cookie from localStorage.

Comment: Wouldn't reloading after reading the cookie result in a loop? The problem is that I will need to inflate the cookie from local storage every time.

Comment: Also, don't I need a custom method to save the cookie to local storage every time it is changed?

Comment: There won't be a loop. Apparently, iOS clears the cookie when the app is closed, and the snippet does the read-cookie-from-localstorage-then-reload when you don't have a cookie. Next time, when you reload, you do have a cookie and there will be no loop. Re: your second question, it seems that it saves it every second (`setInterval`).

Comment: hrrm ok, I don't know how much I like that approach, saving every second, but this is a good start. Thanks.

Comment: One last question, in that script doesn't `document.cookie = '_cookieset_=1';` overwrite the inflation loop?

Comment: No, `document.cookie` is kind of special in that way. It's more akin to "add cookie _cookieset_ with value 1", but I agree, it looks confusing with the `=`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. One extra question if you don't mind. With your understanding of document.cookie what would suggest as a way to set a listener so I can only update localStorage when it changes?

Comment: I don't know how you would do that. If you only ever change the cookie from the server, you should be able to save it after each request. I'm not too sure about it though.

Comment: Ok thanks, yea I could do that but it would be cool to build a generalized client-side module to fix this problem. I will start a new  question, see if anyone has ideas, thanks again.